# Removin NA values in R, without corrupting data frame

Tags: r, kml, na

I am trying to map out the bear population of Norway, but I am running in to some problems with my script.
While trying to convert to kml, I keep being notified that my data contains NA values. 
I've tried na.omit, but this only corrupts my data frame for some reason. I've searched the web and tried everything I've come across, with no success.

Anyone out there who can help me?

**Script** Some of the text is in Norwegian, just look past that

```
library("dismo")
library("maps")
library("raster") 
library("rgdal") 
library("XML")

gbif('Ursus', 'arctos', download= FALSE) #sjekker datasettet for antall registreringer av U.arctos
bjorn <-gbif('Ursus', 'arctos', download= TRUE) #laster ned datasettet fra GBIF

summary(bjorn) #dataene gaar fra 1833 til 2015, med median i 1957 og gjennomsnitt i 1953 (alts?? flest m??linger p?? 50-tallet)
str(bjorn) #7860 registreringer

latbjorn<-(bjorn$lat)
sum(is.na(bjorn$lat)) #4906 registreringer har NA-verdi paa latitude og longitude

longbjorn <-(bjorn$lon)
sum(is.na(bjorn$lon))

land<-table(bjorn$country)
land

norge<- subset(bjorn, country == "Norway", (!is.na(lat+lon)))
summary(norge) #111 verdier registrert
sum(is.na(norge$lat))
sum(is.na(norge$lon)) #35 NA-verdier for latitude og longitude

norgelon<-data.frame(na.omit(norge$lon))
norgelat<-data.frame(na.omit(norge$lat))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(norge$lon, xlab="Lengdegrad", ylab="Antall registrerte Ursus arctos", main="Antall bj??rn registrert per lengdegrad", col= "red")
hist(norge$lat, xlab="Breddegrad", ylab="Antall registrerte Ursus arctos", main="Antall bj??rn registrert per breddegrad", col= "light blue")

norge2<-merge(norgelat, norgelon)
norge2
summary(norge2)

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
map("world")
points(bjorn$lon,bjorn$lat,col="red", pch= 4)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat,col="green", pch= 4)

library("raster")
norgeplot<-getData('GADM',country='NOR',level=0)
plot(norgeplot)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat,col="red",pch=4)
norgeplot2<-getData('GADM',country='NOR',level=1)
plot(norgeplot2)
class(norgeplot)

nor.alt<-getData('alt',country='NOR',mask=T)
class(nor.alt)
plot(nor.alt)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat,col="red",pch=4)


z<-extract(nor.alt,norge[,c("lon","lat")])
summary(z)
par(mar=c(5,6,4,2))
hist(z,col="orange",xlab="Meter over havet",ylab="Frekvens",main="Fordeling av individer p?? moh.")

library(rgdal)
GEO.WGS84<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
norge.sp<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(norge[,c("lon","lat")],norge,proj4string=GEO.WGS84)
writeOGR(norge.sp,"my.pet.kml","Ursus arctos",driver="KML")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `na.omit` separately on your columns will omit `NA` values. But consider what happens here:

```
lat lon
  1  NA
 NA   2
```

What will the result `norge2` look like?

```
lat lon
  1   2
```

… not what we want. Instead, use [`complete.cases`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html):

```
norge2 = complete.cases(norge)
```

This will omit all rows in which any column is `NA`.

Comment: complete cases is not appropriate here as there might be NA values in other fields than lon & lat

Answer (score 1):

Here is your script, fixed and simplified (such that it becomes more instructional).

```
library("dismo")
library("maps")
library("rgdal")

bjorn <-gbif('Ursus', 'arctos', download= TRUE)

# This is how you can remove records with missing coordinates 
bjorn <- bjorn[!is.na(bjorn$lat) & !is.na(bjorn$lon), ]

dim(bjorn)

norge <- subset(bjorn, country == "Norway")

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(norge$lon, xlab="Lengdegrad", ylab="Antall registrerte Ursus arctos", main="Antall bjorn registrert per lengdegrad", col= "red")
hist(norge$lat, xlab="Breddegrad", ylab="Antall registrerte Ursus arctos", main="Antall bjorn registrert per breddegrad", col= "light blue")

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
map("world")
points(bjorn$lon,bjorn$lat,col="red", pch= 4)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat,col="green", pch= 4)

norgeplot <- getData('GADM',country='NOR', level=0)
norgeplot2<-getData('GADM', country='NOR', level=1)

plot(norgeplot)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat,col="red",pch=4)

nor.alt<-getData('alt',country='NOR')
plot(nor.alt)
plot(norgeplot2, add=TRUE)
points(norge$lon,norge$lat, col="red", pch=20)

z <- extract(nor.alt, norge[,c("lon","lat")])
par(mar=c(5,6,4,2))
hist(z,col="orange",xlab="Meter over havet",ylab="Frekvens",main="Fordeling av individer p?? moh.")

library(rgdal)
GEO.WGS84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
norge.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(norge[,c("lon","lat")],norge,proj4string=GEO.WGS84)
writeOGR(norge.sp, "my.pet.kml", "Ursus arctos", driver="KML")
```